# What is the significance of naming the djinni Bartimaeus?

Tags: inspiration, name-significance, the-bible, jonathan-stroud, bartimaeus-sequence

In the [Bartimaeus trilogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bartimaeus_Sequence), the main character is the eponymous djinni **Bartimaeus**, a demon/spirit from "the Other Place" who is cheeky, witty, boastful, and at times surprisingly deep.

[Bartimaeus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bartimaeus), however, is also the name of a man in the New Testament of the Bible. What's the connection there? Does the name in Jonathan Stroud's novels come from this Biblical Bartimaeus, or from somewhere else? Why?

Comment: Could it be that Bartimaeus is metaphorically blind at the beginning of the trilogy, and is healed by the events of the books?

Comment: @PeterShor I can't see how to interpret it that way. Bartimaeus is by far the oldest and wisest of the main characters; if anything, his eye-opening occurred centuries earlier with Ptolemy. But if someone could make an argument to support that reading, I'd definitely be interested.